# Leave iPhone unlocked for a few seconds after closing

Tags: unlock, face-id

With Face Id, the moment the screen blanks out or the moment I press the side button the screen is locked. This ends up being extremely annoying. I unlock the phone, set it on the table, hands are mostly full, screen fades out, I spring to touch the screen but am 0.00001 seconds late. Phone is now locked and I have to put the stuff I'm holding down and physically pick up the phone so that it can see my face just to continue what I was doing.

Similar annoyances happen when wearing a face mask either beacuse it's cold or to avoid spreading/catching a cold (I live in Japan where face masks are common). Mask needs to be off to unlock with Face Id, if the phone locks there's no buffer off a few moments before I have to either take off the mask or else type in the code. Have this happen a few times in a row and I'm ready to smash the phone into a million pieces.

Is there a way to set a 1-5 second delay until the phone actually locks after the screen fads out or even accidentally tapping the side button? Touch Id had (has?) an option to keep the phone unlocked for a brief amount of time which was so much more user friendly in this area. Does the same option exist for Face Id?

Answer (score 1):

In the Face ID & Passcode settings, you could set it to lock after 1, 5, 15 minutes or 1, 4 hours after the screen goes black.

Additionally, you should be able to create an alternative appearance for Face ID to include your Face when you have your mask on? I've set 2 appearances, one with glasses and one without. You may have to reset the Face ID to set up additional appearances though.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

Here's the screenshots in the Face ID & Passcode settings where you can set the time it locks after the screen goes black.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am unable to find the setting to not lock for the phone fro 1,5,15 minutes etc... Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @gman I've added screenshots in my original post. Hope they help.

Comment: I don't get those options. https://imgur.com/uBgeiNu  Any idea how I enable them? iOS 13.3.1

Comment: I just checked, this option only works if you unlock with a passcode. So if you unlock with Face ID, it will lock immediately. If you disable Face ID's iPhone Unlock at the top of the the Face ID & Passcode settings, then you should get additional options in that setting to lock it after 1, 5, 15mins, etc.

Comment: Well then, this isn't actually an answer to the question. But thanks

Comment: @gman my apologies, I thought it works with Face ID (I don't use it personally myself). However as I said previously, you can still set up multiple appearances in Face ID for when you're wearing a mask, so that may help with that issue at least.